# Generate coredump file with SIP enabled

Tags: macos, sip

I've followed the steps to make coredump enable in my machine (mainly by setting `ulimit -c unlimited` and allow write permissions for all `a+x` in `/cores` folder).

However, it seems like It doesn't work while SIP is enabled in my machine `csrutil enable` (I tried sending `kill -11` to `/bin/sleep` running process). When SIP is disabled however, it works just fine.

Does SIP prevent coredump on all processes or only apple signed one ?